# mariadb service not found in centos 8

Tags: centos, mysql, mariadb

On a Centos 8 server I'm trying to install MariaDB and MySQL.

I have used this command

```
dnf install mariadb-server mariadb -y
```

mysql-community-server-5.7.40-1.el7.x86_64 was installed after that.

Now, If i run

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

It says

> Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found.

Along with php I have installed `php-mysql` module, so I have `mysqld.service` but its status is also showing following error

[image: screenshot of systemctl status mysqld.service command]

`mysql -v` shows following error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

**Additional Info:**

Output of `dnf repolist`

| repo id | repo name |
| --- | --- |
| appstream | CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream |
| baseos | CentOS Stream 8 - BaseOS |
| epel | Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 |
| epel-modular | Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64 |
| epel-next | Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Next - x86_64 |
| extras | CentOS Stream 8 - Extras |
| extras-common | CentOS Stream 8 - Extras common packages |
| mysql-connectors-community | MySQL Connectors Community |
| mysql-tools-community | MySQL Tools Community |
| mysql57-community | MySQL 5.7 Community Server |
| remi-modular | Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 |
| remi-safe | Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 |

Output of command `dnf info mariadb-server mysql-server mysql-community-server`

[image: Image: Output of command " dnf info mariadb-server mysql-server mysql-community-server"]

Output of command `systemctl start mysqld`:

> Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[image: Output of command "systemctl status mysqld"]

**Note**: I'm trying to setup an existing project which has its DB in mysql 5.7 so I want to install same version.

Comment: Your screenshot shows no error, as far as I can tell. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I do not see that `mysql-community-server` is available in the CentOS 8 repositories.  The minimum version of `mysql-server` for CentOS 8 should be v8.0 and not v5.7.  Running the command `dnf install mariadb-server mariadb` should have installed the `mariadb-server` and `mariadb` packages with version 10.x and should not install `mysql` packages.  Please add the output of `dnf repolist` and `dnf info mariadb-server mysql-server mysql-community-server` to your question to hopefully straighten things out.

Comment: @MarcusMüller error is this "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)".

Comment: @GracefulRestart I have added the output commands you mentioned on the post. Please review.

Comment: If you meant to install `mysql-community-server` v5.7 then I am not sure why you mentioned `mariadb` in your post.  The error then is that your `mysql` server is not starting.  To start `mysql-community-server` you would run `systemctl start mysqld`.  If that does not work, then post the MySQL error logs.

Comment: @GracefulRestart post is updated and MySQL error logs doesn't have anything

Comment: The error preventing `mysqld` from starting shows up in your `journalctl -xe` output: `[ERROR] Could not open file /var/log/mysqld.log for error logging: Permission denied`.  That location should be writable by the `mysql` user to operate correctly.  There is also another visible error in your output, you are attempting to initialize the `mysql` server, but there are already files there so `mysql_pre_systemd` aborted without completing.

Comment: @GracefulRestart That helped. I have resolved the permission error. But not able to clear mysql data directory. I'm using this command "rm -r /var/libmysql/". Any clue how to cleanup this folder ?

Comment: Hi, @GracefulRestart Thanks a lot for your guideline. I have solved the issue by following the errors mentioned in `journalctl -xe`. If you can kindly add your points as an answer, than i can mark it as accepted.